# azure remote website does not show all my code files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, remote-debugging

I am trying to remote debug my asp.net mvc site on azure. I published my project in debug mode and then look into my remote website folders and it only shows 1 csharp file as opposed to all of them. I don't know why I can't see all of them.

Comment: How are you trying to "remote debug" your web site? By using server explorer in Visual Studio? I'm confused. Why publishing your site in debug mode would publish you source files? Are you using am azure web site or a web role? How are you looking your remote website folders? Sorry for the multiple questions. I'm just trying to understand your problem.

Comment: I'd expect that your MVC site contains no "cs" source files as these will be compiled into assemblies at build time.  If you're seeing "cs" files then they are either CSS files ("css") OR you have marked the action as 'Content' for that "cs" file and it is being packaged and deployed. This isn't an Azure-only issue.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner Sorry, but I'm down-voting your question because of the lack of information. We aren't able to help you with the description you provided.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it's interesting that there were any `.cs` files published. Assuming you published to Azure directly from Visual Studio, the MVC app gets compiled first and then deployed, and there shouldn't be any `.cs` files in the compiler's output.

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fdbz5xd.aspx):

> The compiler produces executable (.exe) files, dynamic-link libraries
>   (.dll), or code modules (.netmodule).

Publishing in Debug mode doesn't change this. From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cw0bt21.aspx):

> The /debug option causes the compiler to generate debugging
>   information and place it in the output file or files.

By way of comparison, all of the "static" files in your project (Views, style sheets, scripts, etc.) get deployed in the same directory structure as your project. But all C# files (Controllers, model classes, custom attributes, etc.) get compiled down to the executable, as quoted above, which then gets placed in the `bin` folder.

As an experiment, try publishing your website to your local machine and inspect the target folder. Assuming your solution contains only the one project (and assuming it's called GiantCorp.AwesomeApp.Web), it will probably be structured similar to this:

```
bin/
    GiantCorp.AwesomeApp.Web.dll // <= all your C# classes compiled to a single executable
    GiantCorp.AwesomeApp.Web.pdb // <= if you compile/publish in Debug mode
    System.dll
    System.Web.Mvc.dll
    ....etc for any required library or .NET assembly dependencies
Content/
    bootstrap.css
    Site.css
Scripts/
    jquery.min.js
    giantcorp.app.js
    ....etc
Views/
    Home/
        Index.cshtml
        About.cshtml
    AwesomeFeature/
        Index.cshtml
    Shared/
        _Layout.cshtml
    _ViewStart.cshtml
    Web.config
Global.asax
Web.config
```